# Is there a loop in msyql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with 2 field present their relation, like the following table

`+-------+-----------+---------+
|   id  | parent_id |   name  |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|   1   |  NULL     |    A    |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|   2   |    1      |    B    |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|   3   |    2      |    C    |
+-------+-----------+---------+`

when I select name from table where id = 1, it will tell me the result is A because the parent_id of A is NULL;

when I select name from table where id = 3, it will finally tell me result is A because B is the parent of C and A is the parent of B.

In PHP we can search it multiple times until the parent_id is NULL. But is there a quick inner loop sql query to solve this problem ?

Comment: What you want is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-examples but it's not available until MySQL 8.0.

Comment: I think you are looking for mysql recursion.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no - you can't loop in simple SQL. You can write a stored procedure in MySQL to run the loop locally on the SQL server to stop the need for multiple round-trips to PHP. Here is the documentation that describes stored procs on MySQL:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

For loops you will also most-likely need a cursor, which is described here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html